# Template parameter to change in a for loop?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a question related to (I think) C++ (prior to C++11 and I cannot upgrade for now) template programming (and “traits”).

My aim:

I have different (but pretty similar) classes (already derived classes from a base class with new functionalities and members).

I programmed a Template class which inherits from any of these classes and uses the polymorphic function “open” to charge from a database all the members and information related to the specific class.

I thought of this strategy because after I want to use this instantiated class (with all its members) as input of other functions.
I could have done it (I think .. but here my template class can inherit from the class in the template parameter…) with a switch/case architecture, but I wanted to avoid it here because it is already heavily used afterwards.

For instance I have classes Derived1 and Derived2 (defined in a Derived.hpp file) which override the function open of their Root parent class.
I have a template function MyClass that once used like 
    MyClass < DerivedType1> currentClass(), or 
    MyClass < DerivedType2> currentClass() does what I want (code below).

**QUESTION:**

**Is it possible to write something which gives me the possibility to make a for loop?**

Something like

```
For (auto i=1; i<N; ++i)
{ 
MyClass<DerivedType[i]> currentClass();
--- other things to do with my currentClass ---
}
```

For me right now my DerivedType(s) are “type” (see the struct in the traits.hpp snippet below) and I don’t even know whether I can put them in a container (like a vector)…
Maybe in C++11 I could have defined an enum class for all the DerivedTypes (is it true?), but here with C++03?

Completely at a lost, I admit…

**Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.**

(working) main

(include “MyClass.hpp”)

```
int main(int, char* [])
{

GlobalClass GlobalItem();  //global class encapsulating all the info of each item from the database

//connection to the database
//DerivedType1 case

MyClass<DerivedType1> CurrentClass();
GlobalItem.AddCurrentClass();

//with a for loop or the like I can use the fact that at each loop the class is declared only inside the { … } and then each time the destructor
//is automatically called
CurrentClass.clear();
CurrentClass = MyClass<DerivedType2>();
GlobalItem.AddCurrentClass();

return 0;
}
```

Here is the template class MyClass.hpp:

(include “traits.hpp”)

```
template <class Traits>
       class MyClass : public Traits::type
       {
       private:
             typedef typename Traits::type BaseType;

       protected:
             std::string         currentType_;


       public:
             //constructor
             MyClass() : BaseType() { this->open() }

//destructor
             virtual ~MyClass();
       };
```

Here the traits.hpp file which is run through by the scope :: operator

(include "Derived.hpp")

```
    struct DerivedType1 {
                    typedef Derived1 type;
       };

       struct DerivedType2 {
            typedef  Derived2 type;
       };
```

Comment: [Nope.](http://www.reactiongifs.com/wp-content/gallery/no/john-cleese-no.gif)

Answer (score 3):

Templates are instantiated at compile time, `for()` loops are evaluated at runtime.
So no, you can't do this.

To *"loop"* over template definitions you can have constructs like e.g.

```
template<int N>
struct A {
     typedef A<N - 1> X;
};

template<>
struct A<0> {
     typedef void X;
};
```

Comment: @MyName There's not all hope gone yet. See my update.

Comment: Hey, this is clever!
I need to understand a little bit better your point ... but, do dig deeper. Definitely!

Comment: @MyName THX ;-). Not a so clever sample, but you seem to have got the grip. That kind of techniques is commonly called [Template Metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming). One of the most prominebt samples is how to create a factorial value using this technique.

Answer (score 2):

With variadic template, you may do something like:

```
template <typename T>
void do_job()
{
    // job for one type

    // MyClass<T> currentClass;
    // ...
}


template <typename ... Ts>
void do_jobs()
{
    // trick to unroll the types sequentially
    std::initializer_list<int>{(do_job<Ts>(), 0)...};
    // In C++17, it becomes simply:
    // (do_job<Ts>(), ...);
}
```

And call it:

```
do_jobs<Derived1, Derived2>();
```